# mongodb shard if I split the shard in 10x smaller

Tags: mongodb

I have 1x mongodb shard 4TB  in single server(512GB RAM) , if I split the shard in 10x shards/partitions in the same server , will the performance will be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Sharding is to give the database more resources (CPU, disk, RAM, bandwidth) than you could fit into a single machine. Spreading the same resources over multiple machines won't help (and creating ten shards on the same machine even less so). You'd just be adding overhead without any benefits. If you end up with ten times the resources in total, then yes, that would help.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe only advantage is if I have 10x different storages attached to same server then I will benefit from 10x IOPS...

Comment: The thing is that currently cpu is almost not used, but in pick hours we reach iops limits... , so maybe if we split to 10x we may add some ussage to cpu but provide some more iops bandwidth?